# Why is it spelled mi yodeya?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, site-name

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The name “mi.yodeya” should really be either “mi.yodey.a” or “mi.yodey-a”](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/the-name-mi-yodeya-should-really-be-either-mi-yodey-a-or-mi-yodey-a)

Shouldn't it be instead mi yode'a (yodeya')?  It is with an 'ayin, not a yud.  Hebrew transliteration is serious business and we should seriously care about these things.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question from the main site](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/764/1172)?

Comment: @ه ه yeah. Adam Mosheh, see answers and comments [there](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/764) and to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2313 for answers to your question, and note that transliteration, in the end, is largely a matter of taste. Any objection to closing this?

Comment: Didn't realize it was a duplicate...  Maybe the other question from the main site should be migrated to here?

Comment: FTR, the 'ayin sound is at the end, so if the apostrophe would represent that, that's where it would go. See the pronunciation note in [our FAQ](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#what-does-the-name-mi-yodeya-mean-and-how-do-you-pronounce-it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See answers and comments to:

- https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/764
- [רָקִיאַע or רָקִיַע](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2313)

…and note that transliteration, in the end, is largely a matter of taste.

Comment: Transliteration is just a matter of taste.  Ideally, the only way Hebrew should be written is in its script, not in English or something else.