# The name "mi.yodeya" should really be either "mi.yodey.a" or "mi.yodey-a"

Tags: discussion, pronunciation, meta

This question is just for the amusement of those who enjoy grammar and pronunciation issues:

The *pasach-ayin* in the word "yodei-a" is pronounced as an inserted *aleph* ending with the gutteral *ayin*, the same way that the *pasach hes* in "mashgiach" is pronounced as an inserted *aleph* ending with a *hes* sound. It is called a "pasuch-genuvah" (the stolen *pasuch*.)
This rule of a letter at the end of a word with a pasach underneath it applies to the *heh*, *hes*, and *ayin*. It can make a big difference in proper pronunciation for reading the Torah and for *tefillah*.

So why is the name of this site "mi.yodeya" which in English would be pronounced "me yo-day-**y**ah", hence adding in a non-existent *yud* into the word?

Comment: Can you cite a source saying that the פתח+עין involves starting with an א sound? I have been led to believe by Semitic linguists that there should be a glide in between and not a stop because it more closely resembles how the word would sound if there were any other final consonant. (This assumption is the reason I have been at peace with the intuitively uncomfortable spelling since the beginning.)

Comment: How about this when I suggest the site I just say Mi yodeah and no one can find it on google so why not just get rid of the dot

Comment: WAF, I've seen it in Radaq, but give me some time to find you the proper citation.

Comment: YS, good point.

Comment: WAF - the Minchas Shai in Beginning of Bereishis cites the machlokes about how the pasach is pronounced.

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2313

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The bottom line is that I went with a transliteration that:

- Points pretty unambiguously to a pronunciation that is not too far off. (Unlike, say "yodea".)
- I find aesthetically pleasing, with the upstroke of the "d" bracketed by the downstrokes of the "y"s.
- Doesn't include punctuation, which is either unavailable or just annoying in URLs. (1)

Like [Shalom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/764/the-name-mi-yodeya-should-really-be-either-mi-yodey-a-or-mi-yodey-a/766#766), I disagree that one necessarily has to interpret the "ey" here as including an extra [yud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yodh) rather than as merely a [tzeireh](http://www.ulpan.net/hebrew-101/diacritics). It's true that my transliterations usually use a plain "e" or an "ei" for a tzeireh, but I chose "ey" here for this situation for the aforementioned reasons.

Also, I admit that I'm generally not entirely consistent with respect to ['ayins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayin), which I sometimes indicate with an apostrophe (mostly, when I need it to separate between vowel sounds anyway) and sometimes don't (2). *Yodeya'* would be more respectful of the final letter, but like I said, that wouldn't work in a URL.

---

1) By the way, if you're wondering how that guiding principle is consistent with the dot between "mi" and "yodeya," note that for your convenience, I set [miyodeya.com](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) and [yodeya.com](http://yodeya.com) to go to the right place.

2) For example, see the title to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/762/arbaa-asar-mi-yodeya).

Comment: Isaac, I do not disagree with your choice. I just see how there could have been other options also acceptable. For a community that is for the most part familiar with the Hebrew, the transliteration does not make much of a difference since we superimpose our knowledge of the Hebrew pronunciation over the overall awkwardness of transliteration. However for the uninitiated it could lead to some comical pronunciations.

Comment: mi.yodeya is actually intended to serve both the initiated and the uninitiated. And, while most of the current active users are, as you say, familiar with Hebrew, we get a great deal of search traffic that you don't see from people googling for basic information about Jewish life and learning. Also, most of the publicity for mi.yodeya to date has been in fora primarily frequented by people who already know a lot about Judaism, but that will hopefully change eventually.

Comment: FTR, this Q&A was posted in Mi Yodeya's [SE 1.0 days](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1/where-did-all-these-posts-come-from), when I had autocratic control of the site, and the preferred name of it was the oh-so-web2.0-y "mi.yodeya" rather than the current "Mi Yodeya."

Answer (score 5):

According to the Sephardic and Judaeo-Arab tradition (including Yemenite), the proper way to pronounce words with furitive patah is to use an epenthetic glide, depending on the vowel: For /e/ and /i/, you add a /j/ (or "y"), and for /o/ and /u/ you add a /w/. Furthermore, the glide must be degush, or doubled. The Israeli (and some Spanish/Portuguese) way is to add an epenthetic alef, or a glottal stop.

So if you're learning the proper Sephardic pronunciation, its "yoDEYya3". With the 3ayin. Israelis would opt for "YoDE'a". I myself end up doing neither option, opting to glide the two vowels together (yo-dea3). Some say this is incorrect, but it's got a solid etymological basis. In related languages like Arabic, the furitive "a" isn't inserted at all.

Comment: B.BarNavi, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for the detailed linguistic note! Please consider registering your account, so that the site can keep track of your contributions no matter where you log in from.

Comment: B.BarNavi, this is very interesting. Perhaps it would fit even better as an answer to [a certain other question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2313) than here?

Comment: B.BarNavi, great answer. I was asking from an Ashkenazic-tunnel-vision perception. Thank you for broadening my mind (and tongue)! :-)

Answer (score 1):

> "mi.yodeya" which in English would be
>   pronounced "me yo-day-*y*ah",

Says who?  yo-day-a .  Just like it's written.

Comment: If you want to pronounce it as it is written then it would be mi yode-ya!

Comment: mi-yo-deya whats the problem?

Answer (score -1):

with this spelling its comes out more precise.

Comment: Huh? What do you mean?