# Mi Yodeya / Mi Yode'a?

Tags: discussion, hebrew

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The name “mi.yodeya” should really be either “mi.yodey.a” or “mi.yodey-a”](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/the-name-mi-yodeya-should-really-be-either-mi-yodey-a-or-mi-yodey-a)

For my first question here I have to ask why "מי יודע" has been transliterated to mi yodeYa and not mi yode'a or mi yodea. "יודע" is written with an "ayin" at the end not a "yod".

Maybe it's for name design requirements or due to English pronunciation ? 
Nevertheless I'm happy to have "stumbled" on this website and hope to read many interesting questions and answers.

Comment: Things are moving fast here... I appreciate the reconsideration of my post, thank you all.

Comment: Ok let's try again: danie7L T welcome to Mi Yodeya! This question is about our site not for our site so I have moved it to our [Meta](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/) site where we discuss policy and whatnot _about_ the site. We are also glad you have stumbled on Mi Yodeya and I hope you contribute by asking and answering questions to the best of your ability. I look forward to seeing you around!